# How to feed Xanitizer results from Gitlab CI (Maven build) to SonarQube?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I am using Xanitizer to run a static analysis on my Java code base. I use the xanitizer-maven-plugin and I have a Gitlab-CI compatible image with Maven and Xanitizer installation. xanitizer-maven-plugin produces a Xanitizer-Findings-List.xml file.

The sonar-maven-plugin feeds my other test results (from Findbugs and PMD) to SonarQube. But not the Xanitizer results. I am not sure if it can.

My SonarQube local installation has Xanitizer plugin installed.

How to feed the Xanitizer results to SonarQube?

Comment: Did you have success with this?  I'm investigating this with Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

The Xanitizer plugin for SonarQube gets the location of the exported XML file from the settings key sonar.xanitizer.xmlReportFile which can be set via a sonar-project.properties file or via the project settings in the GUI.

If the report file is not available on the server that is running SonarQube, it has to be copied to an accessible location before the SonarQube analysis is started.